# onPostExecute not allowing me to create Toast message

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, clipboard, imgur

Please see this before for context: [Anonymous Uploading File object to Imgur API (JSON) gives Authentication Error 401](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16639425/anonymous-uploading-file-object-to-imgur-api-json-gives-authentication-error-4) (it has the code for doInBackground() method in case anyone is interested)

Using an AsyncTask class, I am uploading an image to Imgur. The uploading process is done within doInBackground() method. It returns String link to onPostExecute which should display the link in the form of a Toast message.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
{
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Uploaded! Link: " + result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

However, doing this gives the following error:

*The method getApplicationContext() is undefined for the type UploadToImgurTask*

Trying to copy the return string to the clipboard gives a similar issue.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
{
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager)getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE); 
    ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("label", "Text to copy");
    clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
}
```

*The method getSystemService(String) is undefined for the type UploadToImgurTask*

Comment: use a activity context in place of getApplicationContext(). if asynctask is not a inner class of the activity pass the context to the constructor of the asynctask. use the context to display toast

Comment: Can you demonstrate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Raghunandan is right. So, inside your `UploadToImgurTask` class you can have:

```
private Context context;
//in constructor:
public UploadToImgurTask(Context context){
        this.context=context;
}
```

Then in `onPostExecute` you can simply use:

```
Toast.makeText(context, "Uploaded! Link: " + result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: It worked beautifully! Thanks to both of you.

One more question: my code for copying the link to the system clipboard isn't working from onPostExecute. Keeps saying getSystemService is undefined for UploadToImgurTask. :(

Comment: Again getSystemService() is a Context method, so you need a reference to context object. you can try using `context.getSystemService()`. Hope this works.

Answer (score 1):

In place of getApplicationContext(), use AsyncTask's Parent class name with ".this"  like **MyActivity.this** if it extends from Activity
Otherwise use **getActivity()**. Hoping your problem will be solved with this

Comment: or simply extends Activity

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
public static void pushprofList(Activity context){
 static Context = mConext;

protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

      Toast toast=Toast.makeText(mConext,"Succefully Updated Profile",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
             toast.show();

    }
  }
```

this working completely and display toast message.