# Imgur upload using servlet in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, imgur

I have trying to create a simple upload ui for an image. On the click of the button upload it using the imgur API. And return the image url and display the image.

I have tried to follow this: https://kodejava.org/how-do-i-create-a-web-based-file-upload/ but this is for server upload..

Also tried to follow: [Simple Java Imgur Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29716927/simple-java-imgur-upload)

It would be really helpful if someone could show a simple example.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @RomanC - Sorry had forgotten the last sentence.